# Javascript "".length returning 1 rather than 0

Tags: javascript, string

Ok so I am rather stumped by this one.
I get a string value from a javascript library. I call `myStringVar = myStringVar.trim()` but when I do `myStringVar.substring(0,1)` it gives me an empty string. When I call `var arr = myStringVar.split('')` the first element in the array is and empty string, and when I call arr[0].trim().length it returns 1 instead of zero.

[image]

Am I missing something?

**EDIT**
Following the comments and responses I have been able to isolate the problem down to the existence of a non-visual unicode character at the beginning of the string. I will now try to find a way to remove those characters from the string....or better yet extract the portions of the string that are of interest. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `string.charCodeAt(0)`. What does it say? (I suspect you might have some invisible Unicode character in your string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most likely answer for this is that you have some invisible Unicode character in your string (for instance, `"⁣"`, U+2063 INVISIBLE SEPARATOR).
A string containing only such a character would look to a user (or programmer) like an empty string, but would infact have length 1 since it does contain a character.

One simple way to test if this is the case, is to get the Unicode character code of the character in the string with [`string.charCodeAt(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt). You can then look this up value in a Unicode table (such as [this one](http://unicode-table.com/)), which should tell you if you have an invisible character in your string.

Comment: Your explanation is likely, but I'll be annoyed if it's true -- `INVISIBLE SEPARATOR`s seem like exactly the sort of thing `trim()` should be getting rid of.

Comment: @ChristianTernus I think `trim()` only removes whitespace, although [`INVISIBLE SEPARATOR`](http://unicode-table.com/en/2063/) falls into the category of "General Punctuation", not any kind of Unicode whitespace. In Chrome at least, `trim()` doesn't remove `INVISIBLE SEPARATOR`.

Comment: @ChristianTernus Trim does't get rid of invisible separators. It gets rid of everything in this list: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-white-space , where "Other category" contains these characters (all visible whitespace): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm . It also gets rid of newlines, carraige returns, line separators, and paragraph separators, but that list is exhaustive.

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, but to further the discussion on trim() - it will also not remove a nonbreaking space (&nbsp;) which means that a string with this will appear to just have a space and thererfore a candidate for being .trimmed() but the nbsp will remain even after .trim() has been implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This is quite an annoying. I will test it. Is there some exhaustive list of these invisible Unicode characters so I can include that in my tests or is there some regex I can use to do a replace of invisible characters ?

Comment: indeed myStringVar.charCodeAt(0) = 8234.

Comment: @gavgrif `trim()` does remove non-breaking spaces.

Comment: @Paulpro - thanks - I was under the impression it did not - but if you are sure it foes then I stand corrected - cheers